# SQL changing value to uppercase with specified locale

Tags: sql, sqlite, locale, uppercase

In SQL, is there any function to uppercase a string with specified locale? Function `upper(a_string)` takes one parameter which is not enough for characters other than ASCII ones.

For example, I want to run a statement like this to change all the lowercase characters in a table with values containing Turkish characters:

`UPDATE a_table SET a_field = UPPER(a_field, TurkishLocale);`

Is there any function like this? If not, how can I define it?

Comment: If such a function doesn't exist, you could always use `replace()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [ICU extension module](https://www3.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?ci=d7c816ae15f05f21&name=ext/icu) to get locale-dependent case functions in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Function `UPPER(a_field)` would uppercase the whole cell data. If you wish to Uppercase a specific character of a cell, you could use `REPLACE(a_field, 'tr', 'TR')` to satisfy your need.

Comment: That's what I wish, I want to uppercase whole cell data. For example when I do `upper("Türkçe")`, it returns _"TüRKçE"_ because _"ü"_ and _"ç"_ aren't in ASCII.

Comment: @ShamilAtesoglu i'm afraid  non-ascii characters are unique themselves and have no capital form, maybe this is why they remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collation with case sensitive like

```
 UPDATE a_table SET a_field = UPPER(a_field COLLATE Turkish_CS_AI)
```

Comment: I don't know why but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Same results with `UPPER(a_field)`. For example, `UPPER("Sözcük")` and `UPPER("Sözcük" COLLATE Turkish_CS_AI)` both return _"SöZCüK"_. (And I need to say I am very new to SQL, I don't know much about collation).