# How to set locale with lower() or upper() with Spring Data JPA @Query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The title basically sums it up but my query is like this,

```
@Query("SELECT distinct vr FROM VehicleRequest AS vr, UserUnit AS uu " +
        "WHERE vr.latestAction.vehicleRequestStatus = ?1 " +
        "AND LOWER(vr.appUser.fullName) LIKE %?2%" +
        "AND uu.unit.deleted = false " +
        "AND uu.appUser.id = vr.appUser.id " +
        "AND uu.startAt <= current_timestamp " +
        "AND uu.endAt >= current_timestamp " +
        "AND uu.unit in ?3 " +
        "ORDER BY vr.id")
Page<VehicleRequest> getFilteredRequests(VehicleRequestStatus status, String nameFilter, List<Unit> units, Pageable pageable);
```

I would like to take in to account of the locale with the lower() or upper() functions.

Comment: what is error you are seeing after executing this query

Comment: Actually, %LOWER(?2)% doesn't work for given parameter. I lower it in Java and then pass it as a parameter. So, it's as %?2%. I don't know if LOWER() function takes account of the l10n. So if fullName starts with I and if it lower it to i this is a problem. Because I != i in Turkish. It should be I = ı

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478022/sql-changing-value-to-uppercase-with-specified-locale help? If not, please [edit] your question and add the DB you are using; this may depend on the DB. (Please don't add comments to clarify, code is hard to read in comments. Put everything in the question.) See also [ask].

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you are actually asking about. Right now your query simply doesn't work and it is not at all clear if you are talking about the `lower`/`upper` function in the database or `toUpperCase`/`toLowerCase` in Java.

Comment: @JensSchauder So I edited the question as you asked. Can you understand it now?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL. I fixed the problem by changing the database encoding. But I was wondering if I could just try to change the locale only for LOWER() function or any other function.